# PHP Arrays, foreach can't access complete array elements

Tags: php

I am having trouble accessing array Elements using foreach loop.

```
<?php
    echo "<form method=post action=test.php>";
    echo "Item Name: <input type=text name=item[]>";
    echo "Price: <input type=text name=item[]>";
    echo "Quantity: <input type=text name=item[]>";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<BR>";
    echo "<input type=submit name=submit>";


    if (isset ($_POST['item']))
    {

        $item = $_POST['item'];

    }

    $item = array (

                   $item_name = $item [0],
                   $price = $item [1],
                   $qty = $item [2],
                   );

    foreach ($item as $item)
    {

        echo $item[0];
        echo $item[1];
        echo $item[2];
    }

?>
```

Comment: You don't need foreach to echo those values.

Comment: Why are you using array-style names for your inputs? Why not `name="item_name"`, `name="price", and `name="quantity"`?

Comment: Array-style input names are usually used when you have repeated inputs in a table.

Comment: Actually i want to insert these values to the SQL table, i am echoing them just for test purpose.

Comment: I want to add 15 items in the form and they will be inserted into the SQL table with these fields :
item_name | price | qty

Answer (score 0):

Simple way, is to rename your `<input type=text` by needable fields(name, price, qty) and then get data from $_POST by their names:

```
echo "<form method=post action=test.php>";
echo "Item Name: <input type=text name='name'>";
echo "Price: <input type=text name='price'>";
echo "Quantity: <input type=text name='qty'>";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<input type=submit name=submit>";


$name = "";
if (isset ($_POST['name']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}

$price = "";
if (isset ($_POST['price']))
{
    $price = $_POST['price'];
}

$qty = "";
if (isset ($_POST['qty']))
{
    $qty = $_POST['qty'];
}
```

If you want to use more flexible method with possible list of input fields, then create array of keys with possible field's names and check all existence each key in foreach loop:

```
$all_possible_items_keys = ["name","price","qty","author"];
$items = [];
foreach ( $all_possible_items_keys as $key )
{
    if (isset ($_POST[$key]))
    {
        $items[$key] = $_POST[$key];
    }

}

print_r($items);
```

Output example:

```
Array ( [name] => 11 [price] => 11 [qty] => 22 ):
```

Add names to your `<input type=text` and add it to `$all_possible_items_keys`, then `$items` will hold keys=>value.

Comment: What would i suppose to do, when i have more items, price and qty fields in the form?

Comment: @HarisNoushahi I have added another solutions of your problem to my answer at the end. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, `$item` is just one element of the array, so you shouldn't index it. `$item[0]` is the first character of the element.

It's also confusing to use the same variable for the array and the element in the loop.

Write it like this:

```
foreach ($item as $element) {
    echo $element;
}
```

But instead, you should set up your HTML like this:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php">
Item Name: <input type="text" name="product_name[]">
Price: <input type="text" name="price[]">
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity[]">
<br><br>
Item Name: <input type="text" name="product_name[]">
Price: <input type="text" name="price[]">
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity[]">
<br><br>
Item Name: <input type="text" name="product_name[]">
Price: <input type="text" name="price[]">
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity[]">
<br><br>
Item Name: <input type="text" name="product_name[]">
Price: <input type="text" name="price[]">
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity[]">
<br><br>
...
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then your PHP code can do something like this:

```
$items = array();
foreach ($_POST['product_name'] as $i => $item_name) {
    $price = $_POST['price'][$i];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
    if (!empty($item_name) && !empty($price) && !empty($quantity)) {
        // code to insert into database
    }
}
```

Comment: I have repeat values in my table, i did this just for test purpose.

Comment: Then it should be something like `name="product_name[]"`, `name="price[]"`, and `name="quantity[]"`. They shouldn't all have the same name.

Comment: Hi Barmar, Thank you so much for your help, I have almost completed my project but there is one problem, the HTML form is inserting empty values as well, how may i prevent the script to insert the empty value into the database?

Comment: You can use `if` statements to check if the values are empty before doing the inserts.

Comment: `if (!empty($_POST['product_name'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['price'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['quantity'][$i]))`

Comment: Also, why is `price` an input on the form? Do you let the user set their own price?

Comment: This will generate an invoice/bill.

Comment: Edit the question to show the actual HTML and code.

Comment: I tried editing the question but it showed an error therefore i tried pastebin here is the code: https://pastebin.com/KMwE87js

Comment: That's too big, can you make a smaller example?

Comment: There's no HTML there. What are `item_1`, `item_2`, etc.? Why don't you use meaningful names like `product_name`, `price`, and `quantity` like I suggested?

Comment: See my updated answer that shows the proper way to do it.

Comment: This Answer> if (!empty($_POST['product_name'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['price'][$i]) && !empty($_POST['quantity'][$i]))

Comment: What are you trying to say there?

Comment: Sir, The problem is i want empty fields ignored, for example: if i filled the Item 1 fields so it would only insert Item 1 fields and will ignore the empty fields. But the script is inserting the empty fields along with he filled fields.

Comment: It shouldn't do that, because of `if (!empty($item_name) && !empty($price) && !empty($quantity))`